# After clone from gitlab, when i run the project in Visual studio, it shows an exception but others can run without exception

Tags: gitlab-ci

After i cloned my group project from GitLab, i got a nullreferanceexception towhen i run the application with visual studio,  but my groupmates can run it without any problems. So apparently it is not the project bug.

I tried to clone it  and/or to download from git several times, still the same problems.
Does anyone know what might cause this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Compare line-ending settings: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/.

Get your current configfile contents with: `git config --global --edit` from your commandline.